# UTF-8 wont work when PHP read from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have an code which read from mysql and if I use special characters i get back this �,
I am using UTF-8 on PHP file and on MYSQL.
If I change PHP file to UTF-8 wihtout BOM it shows me but it wont show special characters from html in this PHP.

This is a problem which has to be solved and i tryed many solutions none wont work.
(I'm using mysqli)

```
$sql1 = " SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC ";

if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1)) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<p><b> {$row['name']} </b><br />";
echo "{$row['text']} <br />";
echo "<font size='2'> {$row['date']} </font></p>";
}   }
```

Comment: Post your code, how you insert your data in your database! Do you use any functions before you insert data in your db?

Comment: Make sure the connection to your database is also using this character set

Comment: please visit the following link:http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to get those � printed in your html page, you may use one of the following functions:

```
$string = utf8_decode($string);
echo $string;
```

or:

```
$string = utf8_encode($string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Not working at all. I edited my question now u can see my code in it